# Issue with header in each page after each group in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a main report that have 6 sub report, I built all of them in a individuals tablix, everything is working fine, showing each subreport in an individual tab when I import to excel.
the problem is with one of them, that I have 1 parent group by workArea and one child by Date. I'm showing each WorkArea in a individual tabs as well, that is fine but the problem is the header row is showing only in the first tab. no in the others
How or where I'm lost???
I'm very appreciate if someone can help me please!!!

Thanks in advance

Eliana

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the tablix and go to properties. There should be an option available to "Repeat header rows".